# Can someone help me identify this insect

Tags: entomology

[image]We found this insect in the basement of a friends house. It is about 1 inch in size. My friend lives in Canada

[image]

Comment: Can you please give more information (e.g. size, where do you live, better picture, did you find just one or were there many,  ...)

Comment: It is about 1 inch in size, they are located in Canada, I have another picture but it is a further away one. They only saw one in the basement.

Comment: I actually feel for this guy stuck to the duct tape.  I am a bit different, I admit.

Comment: He was found in a basement furnace room that is usually quite dark. There was recently a worker down there and he was the one that brought him upstairs on the tape. From there they didn't want to touch it since they didn't know what type of insect it was.

Answer (score 1):

This guy looks *very close* to one of the variants of the *very dangerous* [*Triatoma*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triatoma).

I'm not sure what you should do in Canada about those guys, but in Brazil you should report them to your Disease Control Center. *Triatoma* has a very nasty bite and it can trasmit the [Chagas Disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chagas_disease).

It is a bit weird to find this one in Canada - they are usually found in tropical places.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why the downvote? Did I miss something?